# Can I take $\log$ on both sides of inequality such way?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

Can I take $\log$ on both sides of the following inequality
$$f(n) \leq cn^k$$ and get
$$\log (f(n)) \leq kc\log n$$ 
I know that by rules the result inequality should be like this
$$\log(f(n)) \leq \log(cn^k)$$
but I read in book where inequality (1) $\to$ in inequality (2) and want to know which way it was done

**Edit:** this is not general case, the questions relates to the algorithms and O-notation

Comment: Semantic nitpicking, but "add log" is not the best way to put it. "Add" generally refers to te operation of addition, and what you have here is more commonly referred to as "taking logs".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes you can since $log$ is an increasing function and hence preserves the inequality. the main condition is that both sides lies in the domain of $log$ i.e. they are positive
$$\log(f(n)) \leq \log [cn^k]=\log c+\log n^k=\log c+k\log n
$$
If $c >1$ then $\log c>0$ and so
$$\log(f(n)) \leq k\log n\leq kc\log n
$$

Comment: However, $\log(cn^k)\ne kc\log n$ in general.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, sure you are right

Comment: So if this formula applies to algorithms then reform from (1) to (2) inequality is correct? Because k and c are constants and have no significant impact on inequality in general.

Comment: I will your question now, I complete my answer

Comment: @Raf: Um, just because they are constants doesn't mean they "have no significant impact on the inequality". Are you implicitly trying to asymptotic analysis without telling anyone that's what you're doing?

Comment: @Raf if c more than 1 the (2) is true I can explain it for you if it is the case

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes I do, but I suppose maths rules the same regardless of the context.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think he try to prove the inequality (2) so I suggest a condition

Comment: @Raf is this enough, please let me know if you face any problem with it

Comment: @Semsem in general case O-notation define $c$ as positive constant.  I am not sure what $c$ is always more than 1. And of course I want to know why (2) is true if $c > 1$

Comment: @Raf I edit the solution to explain please check it and let me know if you get or not

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get it. Sorry for the long delay before answers, my English is not good as I would like. It's little hard to me to construct English phrases.

Comment: @Raf: Doing asymptotic analysis means that you're allowing yourself to ignore differences that you're not supposed to ignore in other contexts. So the context of asymptotic analysis IS important if you want to use the additional rules that particular context provides you with.

Comment: Does it matter the difference between an increasing function and a strictly increasing function (`log` is strictly increasing)?  The answer says we can `log` both sides because it's an increasing function, even though `log` is actually strictly increasing.  Does this distinction matter? (I know this is like 6.5 years later :P)

Answer (score 8):

You can take the logarithm on both sides of the inequality, if you know the numbers are positive. This produces $\log(f(n))\le \log(cn^k)$.

However $\log(cn^k)$ is not the same thing as $kc\log n$, so your second inequality doesn't follow. What you do have is $\log(cn^k) = \log(c) + k\log(n)$, so you can get
$$ \log(f(n)) \le \log(c) + k\log(n)$$